# create animation of points moving simultaneously in circles about given coordinates

Tags: python-3.x, animation

How can I create an animation of points circling about another given set of points in the 2D X-Y plane?
I have 2 coordinates (0,1) and (10,11) specified by lists `a` and `b` giving the x and y coordinates. I want to show animation of points circling about these given `a` and `b` center coordinates. Function "circle" returns the coordinates of the circling points using circle polar equation where r is the radius and the centers of the rotations are `a` and `b` which are assigned to `cen_x` and `cen_y`.
Problem: When I use the code with `a` and `b` as scalars, it shows the animation, but I cannot increasing the size of `a` and `b`, so if I make them `b = [0 10]` and `a = [1, 11]`, I want to see points moving about circles with the center (0,1) and (10,11). I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 4,3
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

b = 0#[0 10] 
a= 1 #[1  11]    
cen_x = b
cen_y = a

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# set the axes limits
ax.axis([np.min(b) - 10, np.max(b)+10,np.min(a)-10, np.max(a)+10])
# set equal aspect such that the circle is not shown as ellipse
ax.set_aspect("equal")
# create a point in the axes
#for i in len(gnb_longitude):
point, = ax.plot(b, a, marker="o")

r = 2 # radius of circle
def circle(phi):
    return np.array([r*np.cos(phi) - cen_x, r*np.sin(phi) + cen_y])

def update(phi):
    # obtain point coordinates 
    x,y = circle(phi)
    # set point's coordinates
    point.set_data([x],[y])
    return point,

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=1, blit=True, repeat=True,
                    frames=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,360, endpoint=False))
plt.show()
```

I tried the above code. When I use the code on a single center coordinate, it works. But the extension to a set of points doesn't work.

Comment: i build an n-body simulation of galaxy mergers here...  [n-body](https://youtu.be/O1ud-tWPS2c). You can try some of the techniques. But for this i use `pygame` because it is more convenient for animation since it uses a game loop.

Comment: you can also use `fargs=(0,0)` which are function arguments and pass those to the `update` and `circle` functions...

Answer (score 0):

i have updated the `circle()` function with an `offset` to make the point move like this. You can do other versions that suit your code better...

**EDIT**: i just re-wrote the whole code to give a quick example of 2 moving points.  (You can tidy this up and extend the concept to `arrays` or `lists` of points).

Also, you can probably use `classes` which will remove the need for my quick and dirty `global`s.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 4,3
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

b = 0#[0 10] 
a= 1 #[1  11]    
cen_x = b
cen_y = a
offset = 0
offset1 = 0.05

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# set the axes limits
ax.axis([np.min(b) - 10, np.max(b)+10,np.min(a)-10, np.max(a)+10])
# set equal aspect such that the circle is not shown as ellipse
ax.set_aspect("equal")
# create a point in the axes
#for i in len(gnb_longitude):
point1, = ax.plot(b, a, marker="o")
point2, = ax.plot(b, a, marker="o")

r = 2 # radius of circle
def circle(phi, cen_x):
    return np.array([r*np.cos(phi) - cen_x, r*np.sin(phi) + cen_y])

def update(phi):
    global offset
    global offset1
    # obtain point coordinates
    offset += 0.01
    offset1 += 0.015 
    x,y = circle(phi, offset)
    x2,y2 = circle(phi, offset1)


    # set point's coordinates
    point1.set_data([x],[y])
    point2.set_data([x2],[y2])
    return point1, point2

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=1, blit=True, repeat=True,
                    frames=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,360, endpoint=False))

plt.show()
```

Comment: It just shows one circling point which transitions to the other location, not two simultaneous ones.

Comment: @Mat,  i just updated all the code to include an example of 2 moving points...  i did this by extending the `point` variable to `point1` and `point2` variables (and following through with the same logic to the functions)....  you can extend this concept.